# Business Data Connectivity Service Application Stuck in “Stopping” State

Tags: 2010, bdc

My existing BDC service application is not working and it is giving below error in log  when i am accessing it:  **The BDC Service application Business Data Connectivity Service is not accessible. The full exception text is: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.**  So i tried to create new BDC service application but it got stuck in provisioning screen.When i closed the provisioning window the service application was got created but it was not accessible. When i tried to delete this it got stuck in deletion window.After i closed deletion window, the status of BDC service application was  **Stopping**.
Please help.

Comment: no answers, but I'm having a similar problem. Did you ever fix it?

Comment: No...still no solution for this....!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older thread but I'm posting my solution in case it helps someone. I was getting a correlation ID with my error when accessing BDC Service Application in Central Admin.  So, I ran the correlation ID against my ULS logs and found a lot of InfoPath runtime errors in my PRD logs.  I compared by InfoPath settings against a staging farm where BDC Services was working. I found that in General Settings --> InfoPath Form Services --> Configure InfoPath Forms Services Web Service Proxy, there are two check boxes (Enable IPFS Web Service Proxy & Enabled IPFS Web Service Proxy user forms).  In my working farm, I had neither box selected.  In my farm with the error, both boxes were checked.  After unchecking them my BDC service application error went away.  I tested a lot of my forms and all of them appear to still be working with no complaints from users... yet. :)

Comment: In my case there was no InfoPath configuration.

Comment: in my case there  was no infopath involved am still getting the erro. how to remove thee errored out BDC ? i tried to delete the   servappln using powershell. but it failed!